# Waveform generation on FPGA

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, waveform

[image]Can anyone give me an idea on how to generate this RF waveform on FPGA? I already have the I(cos) and Q(sin) signals generated just need a guide to produce this weird shaped pulse. [image]

Edit: This is the output waveform from FPGA. Now, only need to do the digital modulation to get the green graph SSB waveform as posted by @VVT

Comment: I see no pulse. It is not clear where the fpga is in your diagram. Is it intended to be the AWG? This assumes the fpga has dac outputs. What is the waveform you want to modulate the carrier with?

Comment: Yes, the FPGA is the AWG. FPGA outputs sine and cosine waveforms.

Comment: You want to generate the I and Q signals, to feed to an IQ modulator, or you want to generate the final waveform directly (doing IQ modulation on the FPGA itself)? You want to know how IQ modulation works or you want to know what I and Q signals are needed to make a pulse with this shape?

Comment: So then your FPGA has the DACs in it?  That is, what comes out of the FPGA is an analog waveform?

Comment: @user253751 I want to generate the final waveform directly. As VVT rightly mentioned below, I'm looking to generate the green graph which is the SSB modulated signal.

Comment: So you want to implement an IQ modulator in an FPGA? Why can't you simply implement it? What problem did you encounter?

Answer (score 3):

At the scale of the sketch, without axes, it's not possible to determine what sort of pulse 'this weird shape' is, other than 'it starts at zero, smoothly rises and falls again'. It's not even possible to see what the slope at the start is, whether it's finite or zero.

Starting at zero and the smoothness of the pulse seem to be intended to suppress transients, or spectral spreading. One popular pulse that can do this is the Raised Cosine, or 1+cos() envelope. Generate one cycle of cosine, from cos(-pi) to cos(pi), and add 1. You already have a method for generating your trig functions, so just clock through them more slowly.

Another popular pulse shape is the Gaussian. This can be well approximated by a row of [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), which is straightforward to generate in integers, the 'deeper' the row, the better the approximation.

All 'good' pulses (that is, pulses compact in both time and frequency domains) look similar in the time domain, at the scale of your waveform sketch. If you want a catalogue of some other pulse shapes that behave differently to these two in the frequency domain, then have a look at [DFT window functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function), in which both the Raised Cosine (also known as a [Hann window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hann_function)) and the Gaussian are represented.

FWIW, my favourite window is the Gaussian. It can be adjusted with a single parameter. While it is rarely first on the list of best windows for this or that optimisation (main lobe energy, close-in sidelobe suppression, etc, etc), it's always a very good second on all of them, so it makes a good general purpose window or pulse shape.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot give you instructions on how to program your FPGA, given only that you want to have the particular waveform of your picture at the output. Too many unknowns in this request of yours: what are your devices, the programming language, libraries, the IP cores available. The most important omission is what is your task, what you want to achieve, besides the requirement that the waveform should have a characteristic lentil-like shape. But maybe you'll find it useful

**A Crash Course on SSB Modulation**

Start with amplitude modulation. Early technology of radio transmission required the modulation index below 100%, in order to avoid 'overmodulation'. We are taking the modulation signal ('message'), sin(ω<sub>mod</sub>t), non-zero within the time interval 1000 < t < 4000, of cyclic frequency ω<sub>mod</sub> and amplitude 1, and multiply this signal by the carrier signal cos(ω<sub>carrier</sub>t), also of amplitude 1. The resulting waveform is the AM modulated carrier wave with a 100% modulation index:

[image: RF_To_Qubit,_AM]

The blue graph is a modulation signal, the orange graph is the modulated signal.

In the Fourier transform of this signal, in the range of nonzero signal, you see two peaks at frequencies of \$ω_{carrier} \pm ω_{mod}\$, in full agreement with the frequencies f<sub>carrier</sub> = 50, f<sub>mod</sub> = 10, which you can calculate from numbers in the plot titles ("carrier cos(2π·t/1000·10) t ∈ [0, 5000); message sin(2π·t/1000·2) t ∈ [1000, 4000); RFout(t) = carrier(t) * message(t)", for the data array size of 5000, the horizontal axis unit is the 1/5000 time tick).

[image: RF To Qubit, AM, Fourier]

Now, if we are tasked with only shifting the signal frequency into a lower or higher end, avoiding the conversion of a single-frequency signal into a mix of two frequencies, we can filter out undesired frequency. But digital signal processing offers the technique to translate the signal frequency without filtering. This can be performed with the help of Hilbert transform. We complete the modulation signal with the imaginary component, which is a Hilbert transform of our real modulation signal. Notice that MATLAB and Python 'hilbert' functions, when applied to a real function, produce a complex output with the real part equal to the source real data, and the imaginary part equal to a Hilbert transform of the source real data in the mathematical sense of the word.

Read the following, IF and ONLY IF your are tasked with the SSB-like frequency translation of the carrier wave.

First, you have to perform the Hilbert transform of your modulation function. In the 'I' (in phase) channel of your AWG you show the function sin() that starts at time tick 200 ns (and I guess stops somewhere after 1 us). I will take this as a real part of the modulation signal. You have to compute the 'Q' (quadrature) part with the Hilbert transform. I don't know if your AWG supports the Hilbert transform as a built-in function, if not, you have to program it yourself. If you want to SSB-modulate the carrier using the Hilbert transform approach, you should have at your 'I' (Ch.1) and 'Q' (Ch.2) channels the waveforms that look similar to these:

[image: AWG_Ch.1_Ch.2]

The orange graph is a modulation signal itself and the real part of the I/Q complex signal, the green graph (imaginary part) is the Hilbert transform of the source real signal.

Now, the product RFout(t) = hilbert(carrier(t)) · hilbert(message(t)) is the carrier(t) signal, SSB-modulated with the modulation function message(t). Output of the function hilbert() follows the convention of MATLAB and Python 'hilbert' functions. For the sine train modulation signal, as in your update to the post, it looks still more 'weird', but it is what you've got for your modulation signal.

[image: RF_To_Qubit,_SSB]

Because the hilbert() function is complex, basically we can construct two type products: the hilbert(carrier(t)) ·* hilbert(message(t)) and hilbert(carrier(t)) · conjugate(hilbert(message(t))), where `conjugate` is the complex conjugate. The other combinations can be derived from these. The Fourier transform of the product hilbert(carrier(t)) · conjugate(hilbert(message(t))) is drawn in blue, the Fourier transform of the product hilbert(carrier(t)) · hilbert(message(t)) is drawn in orange.

[image: RF_To_Qubit,_SSB,_Fourier]

You see that hilbert(carrier(t)) · conjugate(hilbert(message(t))) gives the lower side band (LSB), and hilbert(carrier(t)) · hilbert(message(t)) gives the upper side band (USB).

Back to generating the lentil-shaped RF output that is so pleasing to you.

Now, the modulation signal is the sort of 'raised cosine' function 1-cos(ω<sub>mod</sub>t) (not exactly, but similar).

[image: RF_To_Qubit,_AM,_1-cos]

The main characteristic of this pulse is that it is only one period of the modulation frequency, so we can hardly expect the modulation frequency peaks resolved in the Fourier transform of this signal.

[image: RF_To_Qubit,_AM,_1-cos,_Fourier]

We see only a peak at the carrier frequency position. The peak is widened, but no traces of the modulation frequency shifts, which can be easily distinguished with the long sine-train modulated signal.

Let us see if the SSB would make the waveform more interesting. The waveforms (real and imaginary parts) of a Hilbert transform of the 'pseudo raised cosine' modulation signal:

[image: AWG_Ch.1_Ch.2,_1-cos]

The carrier, SSB modulated with this modulation signal, real and imaginary parts:

[image: RF_To_Qubit,_SSB,_1-cos]

And the Fourier transform perfectly resolves the lower side band and upper side bands:

[image: RF_To_Qubit,_SSB,_1-cos,_Fourier]

A word of caution: the raised-cosine (as well as Gaussian, etc) pulses can be and are used in communication applications, but you better make sure for yourself that it is what you are supposed to design. The signal waveforms may appear similar, with the phase/frequency characteristics of the signals being entirely different.