# Amplitude modulation on FPGA

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog

I'm trying to implement amplitude modulation on a Xilinx Vivado using Verilog HDL, but can't seem to get the proper output. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

This is in reference to my last post titled [*Waveform generation on FPGA*](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/612798/waveform-generation-on-fpga) where  senior member V.V.T suggested I implement AM first.

Edit: I modified the code to include signed signal input (sine_carrier and sine_env) and it seems to work fine. However, I had to multiply the AM equation by some constant (gain I think?) to increase output level.

```
// digital modulation block which takes clk, rst and carrier 
// frequency as input and outputs an AM wave

module digital_mod(clk, rst, fcw_carrier, am_out);
parameter N = 16;
input clk, rst;
input [N-1:0] fcw_carrier;
output reg [33:0] am_out;

wire [N-1:0] fcw_env;
assign fcw_env = 16'b0000001010001110;  // frequency of modulating
                                        // signal = 654 * fclk/2^16 = 1MHz

wire signed [N:0] carrier_in, env_in;

// ddfs is a module that generates sine wave (17-bits) 
// of frequency fcw_in using CORDIC algorithm

ddfs DDFS1(clk, rst, fcw_env, env_in);
ddfs DDFS2(clk, rst, fcw_carrier, carrier_in);

// frequency of carrier (specified in testbench) = 10MHz

always @(posedge clk or posedge rst)
begin
if (rst)
begin
    am_out <= 0;
end
else
begin
    am_out <= 10*(carrier_in*(1 - 0.8*env_in));  // standard AM equation
                                                 // y(AM) = sin(wc*t)(1-M*sin(wm*t))
                                                 // M = modulation index = 0.8??
end
end
endmodule
```

[image: AM Output]

Comment: Your sin_env waveform is surprisingly ragged, you might want to find out why. Your AM out shows signs of overflow and wraparound in those negative excursions. I don't see any signed/unsigned distinction in your code. Shouldn't your modulated carrier output be more like carrier(t) x (1+AM_depth x sin(mod(t)), where carrier and mod are signed, 1 and AM_depth unsigned ?

Comment: does `env_in*carrier_in` look as expected?

Comment: @Neil_UK Hi. Thank you for the reply. I used signed signal and now think output is fine. Please have a look. Do you have any more suggestions for me?

Comment: sin_env still looks ragged, that may or may not be an issue depending if the simulator display does funny things. It looks like you've generated DSBSC (Double Sideband Suppressed Carrier), not AM, you'll see the phase of the carrier is inverting every modulation half cycle, which is what you'd get from carrier(t) x mod(t). That's what the 1+ term in my first comment does, puts a carrier into the signal, while the AM_depth x controls the level of the AM.

Comment: Without the carrier (the "1+"), the receiver has no reference to compare the modulation against, so if AM worked like this, volume would be dependent on distance to sender.

Comment: You have now basically `env_in*carrier_in` which is [DSB-SC modulation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-sideband_suppressed-carrier_transmission). You do need to add the carrier for it to be AM.